# how to display arrow only on Select control

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there anyway to display the arrow only for a html select control
I found the example below but it doesnt work for IE...

```
<select style="width:18px">
<option value="10000">Something</option>
<option value="100">Other thing</option>
<option value="1">The last option</option>
</select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Fs7G5/

Comment: it does work in IE, it's just a little too narrow, try `style="width:25px;"`

Comment: in ie 11 i get a slight white space to the left of the arrow

Comment: ... thats pretty much what I said, it's too small, make it bigger. You tried? No you didn't!

Comment: if i make it bigger the white space gets bigger, make it smaller and arrow gets truncated

Comment: the white-space is bigger in internet explorer

Comment: yes but i dont want this white space displayed at all

Comment: Setting the font-size for the select element to 0, and then reset it when it gets focus can achieve a similar result: http://jsfiddle.net/Fs7G5/30/ works in IE 11, too. Disadvantage is that you have to specify the height of the select element as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could detect whether the user is using Internet Explorer and then change the `select` element width accordingly.  If you want to minimize the white space that shows up on the left hand side of the drop down, you can also set the `margin-left` setting of the element to a negative value.

```
function msieversion() {
    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");
    return msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./) ? true : false;
}

if(msieversion()){
    // I added a #myselect ID to the element, but if you don't want to,
    // you can still get to the element using another JS selector
    var element = document.getElementById('myselect');
    element.style.width = '25px';
    element.style.marginLeft = '-7px';
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Fs7G5/28/

Comment: "but i dont want this white space displayed at all " -.-

Comment: In this example the whitespace is simply hidden to the left hand side of the viewport. But if its left edge were not aligned to the edge of the viewport, you'd still see the whitespace. If you put it inside of a container with `overflow: hidden` you'd incidentally crop the actual dropdown selection window, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like the arrow to be of a bigger size, here is one [workaround](http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/) by c.bavota using CSS.